# What is the meaning of "breaking" in tv show "breaking bad"

Tags: meaning

Searched wiktionary but seems none of the explanations in it makes sense.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breaking_bad

Comment: Don’t feel bad: I had no idea what it meant either, and I’m a native speaker. I’m just not hip to “Suthun” slang. A more widely used synonym would appear to be “going bad” used with reference to a person who became a black sheep, not to spoiled milk. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to look up the term [**break bad**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/break_bad):

> *(colloquial, southern US)* to go wrong, of people or events, including to turn toward a life of crime or immoral activity

The title of the series is a play on the phrase.

Comment: Thanks, I think that makes sense since it's happening in the southern US!

Answer (score 4):

> [***break***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/break) : (copulative, informal) To suddenly become.
>       *Things began **breaking** bad for him when his parents died.*
>       *The arrest was standard, when suddenly the suspect **broke** ugly.*

Comment: +1, but it's interesting that this comes from Wiktionary, which the OP has already looked at...

Comment: It's also interesting that Wiktionary has this sense defined under the lemma 'break' **and** a separate MWV entry for 'break bad' (Amory's link).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Wiktionary's goal (which it is far, far from) is truly massive.  Definitions, etymology, pronunciation, and synonyms for every word and phrase from every language on Earth.