# What's the verb to describe a good guy becoming a bad guy?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for a verb to describe the action of a good guy becoming a bad guy. There is a word for it in my mother language, but I am not sure if there is a word for it in English.

The verb, which could be literally translated as 'become bad, turned into a bad guy'. an example would be:

> He used to be a good cop, but now he___,  mingles with the gangsta on the street, sad thing.

update: thanks everyone for your answers and comments. it seems a word to describe this behavior of people working in law enforcement is unanimous, but a word to describe this behavior that includes ordinary folk seems remains controversial.

Comment: "Flip(ped") is a common term.

Comment: Not a verb, but **tarnished**.

Comment: A word to describe this behavior that includes ordinary folk will remain controversial because everyone has their own moral code. Corruption is in the eye of the beholder unless there is a job description. For instance, Hank Voight, on the TV show CPD. At first glance he seems bad because he mingles with the crooks, but that's how good cops get stuff done. Remove this whole god cop / bad cop thing if you want to talk about the rest of us. Further adding to the confusion, IMO, (good cop / ) "bad" cops aren't necessarily *crooked* cops.

Comment: If [*debaucherize*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/debauchery) was a word (*debauchery* : 2. *Archaic*. seduction from duty, allegiance, or virtue.) it would work.

Comment: Oh, the verb is *debauch*. [*cough*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/394876/68817)

Comment: go or turn bad seems ok, though usually reserved for milk

Comment: "Wised up?"  ... or were you looking for a less cynical option?

Comment: I'd say he *fell from grace*.

Comment: Dependant on the circumstances you could say he became **vindictive**

Comment: @Michael That's not a bad choice! *Fallen angels, fallen women.*

Answer (score 78):

One could also use the word *turned*; e.g.:

> He was once an honest politician, but having been exposed to the crime syndicates for so long, now he's been turned.

Comment: It seems to me that some construction using "turned" is the most common to express the idea.

Comment: And if you're looking for a noun, maybe [turncoat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turncoat) would work.

Comment: @JohnWu in that case just use traitor (or Benedict Arnold if you're feeling like making someone mad)

Comment: @StephenS I wouldn't use "Benedict Arnold" unless you don't intend for non-Americans to read your writing.

Comment: You can also use *turned* as an intransitive verb--it will drop right into "but now he *turned*".

Comment: "Turned" is more specific than just going from good to bad. It means that there was an organized group, opposed (in some sense) to the one the person was working for, which recruited the person away -- possibly while leaving her/him in place. So the politician was turned by the mob, or the spy was turned by an unknown intelligence agency, but a cop who turns to a life of crime hasn't been turned, just corrupted.

Comment: P.S. It's a great term, if it describes what you want -- but I'm not entirely clear on what that is.

Comment: "turn" is good verb yet works both ways as "turn" in itself does not imply the _direction_ of the change as in "He turned".  I suspect OP will need a verb with a qualifier

Comment: @chux In this context, "turned" implies a near 180-degree turn to some belief or course of action highly opposed to the former course.  One wouldn't term a gentle change in perspective a "turn" in this context.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Agree  about  near 180-degree "turn".  Re-state: "turn" does not, in itself, differential between "a good guy becoming a bad guy" or "a bad guy becoming a good guy" without additional qualification.

Comment: Oh come on, someone has to say it: [If he could be turned he would become a powerful ally.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiHGGuLCrcc)

Answer (score 55):

[to **corrupt**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/corrupt)

> - to destroy the integrity of; cause to be dishonest, disloyal, etc., especially by bribery.
> - to lower morally; pervert
> - to alter for the worse; debase.

In your sentence it could be used as:

> ...but now that he was corrupted, he mingles with...

---

Other options include:

- debase
- infect
- pervert
- taint
- warp

Comment: I think this answer is more universal to the English speaking world, where the other answers seem more USA oriented.

Comment: Based on my experience when reading fictions, the genre "corruption" is the exact term that describes OP's situation.

Answer (score 34):

For a wrestling reference you could use [turned heel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heel_(professional_wrestling)). In professional wrestling 'good guys' are 'babyfaces' (more commonly just called 'faces'), and the 'bad guys' are heels. When a wrestler changes it's called 'turning'. Thus, a good guy going bad in wrestling is 'turning heel'.

Comment: This is also what they call it on TV Tropes (WARNING: destroyer of free time): [Face-Heel Turn](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FaceHeelTurn)

Answer (score 30):

Your cop has gone rogue.

"Going rogue" commonly means defying orders or convention to the degree that one is assumed to have left the organization or movement. He might never be a good cop again.

Comment: I feel like going rogue has less of a "bad guy" connotation, and more of a "he pursues his goals outside of the regulations set by his organization," which *could* mean bad (as in "bad-guy"), but doesn't necessarily.

Comment: This feels like a very American English expression - I'd like to see speakers of other dialects chime in on how common it is in their dialect.  (We do hear it in Canadian English, but our English has a lot of AmEng terms.)

Comment: Rogue used to describe a cop definitely conveys that [the cop has](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047424) [become a criminal](https://www.policeone.com/health-fitness/articles/6120461-The-Dorner-case-When-cops-turn-rogue-and-how-to-prevent-it/), it doesn't just mean "unconventional methods."

Comment: Axel Foley went rouge but he was not a "bad cop". [Breaking the law](https://unicornbooty.com/beverly-hills-cop-crooked-police/) doesn't make you a bad cop. Only moral bankruptcy can do that.

Comment: @Mazura Be careful!  *Rouge* is an entirely different word (a shade of red, a type of makeup for the cheeks, or the single point score allowed in Canadian football) than *rogue*.  The former is pronounced something like "roozh".

Comment: "Gone rogue" does not imply criminal activity.  In fact, it could even mean that your cop _refuses_ to engage in criminal activity when everyone else in is department has been corrupted.  See http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Gone%20Rogue and https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/were-going-rogue

Answer (score 27):

Break bad: (colloquial, especially Southern US and Midwestern US, of a person) To go bad; to turn toward immorality or crime

E.g.
*But somehow he broke bad when he was just a yearling boy, started running around at night with a bad crowd, drinking beer and wine, and fighting and getting in all kinds of trouble and wouldn't go to school.*

[Reference](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/break_bad)

Comment: I would say that, TV series titles aside, this is likely not to be understood by many listeners.

Comment: Midwestern US here (raised in Chicago suburbs); I've never heard this phrase outside of that TV show's title.  Before even reading Muzer's comment, when I saw this answer I was like, "Oh, so that's what that means?"

Comment: If anything, I think the show's title being so familiar adds to the credibility of this being the preferred answer.  Perhaps it was not a particularly common term before, but it certainly has much wider adoption now as a result of the series.  I may have heard it fewer than five times in my life before the show aired, but I am surprised that anyone from the US would have been totally unfamiliar with the term - especially after knowing about the show.

Comment: @DarrenRinger the phrase itself is now more widely recognized, but I don't think its usage in this sense is.

Comment: @Kevin But it would likely be understood, which may be all that's needed.

Comment: @called2voyage I would wager that most who hear the term "breaking bad" think of the TV series first, then those who have seen the series recall the meaning of the phrase by remembering the ONE scene in the series where it was used in a sentence.

Comment: @vijrox The meaning is not hard to figure out if you know a one-liner description of the point of the show. I have never watched it and didn't know the meaning of the phrase before it was used as the title of the show.

Comment: Until the tv show, I'd never seen anyone use the phrase "break bad". Since the tv show, I've seen *tons* of people use the phrase "break bad": 100% of the time, as a synonym for "make meth".

Comment: Relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/124299/48426 and https://english.stackexchange.com/q/174891/48426

Comment: FWIW, I've never heard it used as a synonym for "make meth".  I am surprised that so many people appear to be confused about a phrase that most definitely existed before the show, and in fact answers the question perfectly well.  I guess this is a glimpse into why regional dialect stays so regional - apparently it is nonsense to everyone else.

Comment: Southwestern US, I never heard it until the TV show.

Answer (score 23):

Maybe this is a Midwestern thing, but I'd say something like, "He used to be a good cop, but now he's gone crooked, mingles with the gangsta on the street, sad thing."

A bit like "broke bad," but I'm guessing crooked is understood more widely.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing.  He went evil, or he's gone evil.

Comment: *"It got into my hand and it went bad"*

Comment: On a similar note, in the UK a corrupt police officer might be known as a `bent` copper.

Answer (score 21):

How about:

***[went over to the dark side](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/the-dark-side.html)***

> The evil and malevolent aspect of human personality or society, often referred to in a lighthearted or comic context.

Comment: "*go over to* the dark side" sounds more idiomatic to me, but +1

Comment: Might too jocular for the example.

Answer (score 18):

Perhaps your guy has *fallen* as in a [*fallen angel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_angel).

He "fell" implies one was on a good path, yet not only has stumbled, but is down (bad) and no longer upright.

Comment: I think fall has too many meanings for it to be properly construed in this context, absent a qualifier. "He used to be a good cop but he fell," to me, makes it sounds like he was killed.

Comment: @Noah True.  As OP asked for a verb, "fall" with context does work well with "'fall from grace", "fall off the bandwagon", "fallen angel",  Like other answers, _break_, _go_, _move_, something more than just a verb is needed.

Comment: I'd suggest you say that he's fallen rather than fell / fall

Comment: along these same lines: "fall from grace"

Comment: UV - however, term should not be fell. "He used to be a good cop, but now he ***has fallen***, mingling with the gangsta on the street. A sad thing."

Answer (score 16):

Consider ***strayed*** which, in the context, implies *good guy becoming a bad guy*.

> He used to be a good cop, but now he ***strayed*** and mingles with the gangsta on
>   the street, sad thing.

Collins:

> **[stray](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stray)**
>   *verb* (intransitive)
>
> **4.**  to deviate from certain moral standards
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers
>
> Parents feel distressed by children who have strayed.

Comment: From all the answers in here, this seems the most appropriate one, since _straying_ actually implies a literal **deviation from a "good path"**, while _turning_ can be used in both "ways" and may imply that there was a [specific trigger, as Charles suggested in a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394789/whats-the-verb-to-describe-a-good-guy-becoming-a-bad-guy#comment935390_394815).

Comment: To me *stray* has a temporary feel. As in, he strayed but got back on track, for example in a marriage. As opposed to *fallen*, which is not  sideways and reversible but downward and virtually irreversible, like with a fallen angel. Actually, the example with the children illustrates the point pretty nicely.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, it is possible to _stray_ and be lost permanently as much as it is possible to _fall_ and get up.

Answer (score 10):

"Degenerate" seems the best single, non-colloquial word.

X wrote an interesting first novel, but he has degenerated since then.

The word has a different meaning when used as a verb than when used as an adjective or substantive.

Answer (score 9):

He **defected**.

Merriam Webster:

> 1. To forsake one cause, party, or nation for another often because of a change in ideology
> 2. To leave one situation (such as a job) often to go over to a rival

EDIT: I should add that your word choice depends on the tone of the writing. If it's modern or casual, *turned* works well. If it's more formal, *defected* would fit better.

Comment: Defection would imply a change of faction, so in the example, if the good cop quit and became a gangsta then "defected" would fit. However, if he remained a cop but was simply no longer good, I'm not sure that "defected" would really apply.

Comment: Defected works both ways. He was in the mafia but deflected and now works as an informant for the cops.

Answer (score 5):

**debase**, de·base \di-ˈbās, dē-\ transitive verb

> 1:  to lower in status, esteem, quality, or character. *debased himself by lying to his supporters* –[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debase)

---

> ***debase, vitiate, deprave, corrupt, debauch, pervert*** mean to cause deterioration or lowering in quality or character. *debase* implies a loss of position, worth, value, or dignity.

---

> To *debase* something is to make it corrupt or impure. –[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/debase)

---

> He used to be a good cop, but he *debased* himself by mingling with the gangstas on the street.

Comment: Not sure if this is right - in my understanding a good person being debased remains good but kind of tainted or hurt. Not the meaning OP was asking for. Sorry, I think I must downvote.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg - "remains good" is in the eye of the beholder after someone's character deteriorates or lowers in quality to a point which implies a loss of position, worth, value, or dignity, or having (what, in the eye of the beholder, is) corrupt or impure virtue.

Comment: This answer started off pretty good but now people keep debasing it. The 'worse' it becomes at this point, the more correct it is as an example unto itself.

Answer (score 4):

> He used to be a good cop, but now he has **become corrupt** and mingles with the gangsta on the street, sad thing.

Answer (score 2):

If the cop turned due to too much hanging out with thugs, you could say he's gone native.

> adopt the lifestyle or outlook of local inhabitants, especially when dwelling in a colonial region; to become less refined under the influence of a less cultured, more primitive, or simpler social environment.

Comment: "*If the cop **turned** [...]*" +1 to Jim MacKenzie

Comment: @OhBeWise   It seems turned is most accepted to use here, like this answer itself. btw, your reply of this answer is really refreshing.

Comment: It's genuinely funny that I got two comments on my answer expressing support for a different answer. I voted for that answer too.

Comment: @stannius  it's not a support of that answer, it's a reply of that previous comment. i just said that it seems that word is mostly accepted here…btw, i upvoted your answer too.

Comment: Worth noting that this phrase can have strong imperialist/colonial overtones, and should possibly be avoided in favor of other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Dependent on context, you could go with something like succumb

> fail to resist pressure, temptation, or some other negative force.

Though I guess you'd like something more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

There is a phrase to describe this event in American professional wrestling: The [heel turn](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101011210205AAU94l6). It's still possibly too esoteric for your needs, but it's definitely not got a law enforcement origin.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's helpful to me as it extents the length of my knowledge about these word. btw, i am a Yahoo answer user too.

Answer (score 1):

If the person was previously a bad guy, then became good, and is now becoming bad again, you could say he's *regressed*. (Though this is sometimes a psychiatry term too.)

Answer (score 1):

He used to be a good cop, but now he degenerated, mingles with the gangsta on the street, sad thing.

If he had been bad and then turned bad after being good for a while one could say he "backslid" or 'relapsed".